# Can @ConditionalOnProperty use a nested property value?

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, yaml, spring-config

I want to do something like:

```
@ConditionalOnProperty("${${appname}.someVal}")
@Controller
public class MyController {...}
```

Where my yaml would have:

```
appname: myapp
myapp:
  someVal: true
```

How would I do this?

*EDIT: This does not work:*

```
@Value("#{'${appname}.someVal'}")
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To evaluate SpEL, use `@ConditionalOnExpression` instead of `@ConditionalOnProperty`.

Does not look very elegant, but here it is:

```
@ConditionalOnExpression("#{environment.getProperty('${appname}.someVal') == 'true'}")
```

`environment` references a bean that implements [`org.springframework.core.env.Environment`](https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/core/env/Environment.html) which is available in every Spring Boot application out of the box.

Comment: Where does it get the "environment" from?